# How in a Serverless Project make an external DB work when deployed to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, typeorm, serverless-framework

UPDATE: I don't know WHY I have been voted against! The code got an error when initialising the ORM, I started a new project and made it work.

In my project https://github.com/arcovoltaico/nextjs orm.config.ts I tested my external DB by hardcoding its details. It works nicely when I run the app locally. But after deploying it to AWS I'm getting this error:

```
Access denied for user 'myuser'@'ec2-xxxxxxxx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com' (using password: YES)
```

My DB Host have told me that they can't see any attempt from that server.
I have also tried adding this code to my main handler (the single entry point lambda) :
`context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;` making no difference at all.

If from my laptop I run  `mysql -hcp.myhost.com -myuser -p`  I can access it.

Any ideas? Cheers!

Comment: "Access defined for user ..."  typically means the process was able to reach the server, but not able to login. What hosts are allowed for `myuser` on the mysql server?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things that came to mind that you can try:

1. Check that the deployed app and the db are able to communicate (same VPN network; check Firewall rules; ping db from deployment server...)
2. Check user access right on database (thought you said locally you were able to connect, but was that the same user/pass as server, was in maybe windows login....)
3. Credentials which are installed locally for CLI tools to connect to cloud providers are often overlooked and forgotten by developers ("works on my machine" :) - so check it from a different machine)
4. Check logs and provide more data

NOTE: sorry if this sound condescending, it is not intended to.